# How to bind an Image from App Component to HTML file in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

How to bind an Image from App Component to HTML file in Angular 2
This is my Relative path : assets/images/MyProfile_Summary_1x.png

```js
export class MyProfile  {

image :"./assets/images/MyProfile_Summary_1x.png";

}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#over img {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="over" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%">
                            <img [src]="image">
                        </div>
```

Comment: You need to [sanitize it](https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer)

Comment: try `"assets/images/MyProfile_Summary_1x.png";` instead

Comment: Hi @Jitender , I have tried but unable to get the image...

Comment: What exactly the error you are facing @Sundeep?

Comment: can you create [Stacbliz](https://stackblitz.com/) demo of your problem or add the console output here if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, you are using `colon` operator which is used for defining the type of any variable in `ts`

so you just need to replace this

```
image :"./assets/images/MyProfile_Summary_1x.png";
```

with

```
image = "./assets/images/MyProfile_Summary_1x.png";
```

> if you still face the same issue then please verify your file path as
>   well.